# Implicit conversion Must be used Explicitly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, nullable, implicit-conversion

I have a struct with the following operator declared :

```
public struct myStruct {
    public static implicit operator int(Nullable<myStruct> m){
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

This operator alone lets me implicitly convert a **non-nullable** struct to int, but trying to implicitly convert its nullable counterpart still raises a compilation error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type `myStruct?` to `int`. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Apparently the mentioned "explicit" operator is actually the implicit operator I declared, removing this operator altogether also removes the mention of the explicit one.

When it comes to nullable structs, why am I being forced to use this operator explicitly even though it was declared implicit?

---

**EDIT:**
So here is the "full code", stripped of everything that doesn't make the compiler error disappear. The struct stays literally the same, all that's new is my testing code :

```
using System;

public struct boilDown {
    public static implicit operator int(Nullable<boilDown> s) { return 0; }
} // END Struct

public class Sandbox {
    void Update ()
    {
        boilDown nonNullable = new boilDown ();
        Nullable<boilDown> NullableVersion = new Nullable<boilDown>();

        int MyInt;
        MyInt = nonNullable;        // this work thanks to my operator
        MyInt = NullableVersion;    // But this line requires an explicit cast
    }
}
```

---

**VERSION :**
You all hinted me at a c# version issue.
I'm working on Unity 2017.1.0f3, which rather than .Net, uses Mono 2.0.50727.1433. (This apparently is a NET3.5 Equivalent, but even their experimental NET4.6 equivalent has this issue.)
I'll ask this question to them and see what they say.

Comment: Try it with "int?"

Comment: Give us entire code.

Comment: Full code coming right up. After boiling it down to the bug, there isn't anything new to see in the struct itself, only the testing code.

Comment: Implicitely converting to an int? (while having the operator still set up for a non nullable int) will work indeed, but this breaks the point of an implicit operator: I don't uses int? everywhere it's still gonna need a cast.

Comment: You can explicitly cast that.`MyInt = (int)NullableVersion;`

Comment: what version of C#? Console-App 4.6.1 is fine with it, no errors or warnings.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ with 4.5 - fine as well...

Comment: Not sure, I've been working on Unity 2017.1.0f3. From what I gatherer: Unity uses Mono instead of .NET, and my Mono version is 2.0.50727.1433. If you all say the code works fine, I guess I'll go ask my question to the folks at Unity themeselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all who told me this code *should* compile.
Unity confirmed this error to be a bug on their end.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly cast the `NullableVersion` to `int` like below.

```
using System;

public struct boilDown {
    public static implicit operator int(Nullable<boilDown> s) { return 0; }
} // END Struct

public class Sandbox {
    static void Main()
    {

    }
    void Update ()
    {
        boilDown nonNullable = new boilDown ();
        Nullable<boilDown> NullableVersion = new Nullable<boilDown>();

        int MyInt;
        MyInt = nonNullable;        // this work thanks to my operator
        MyInt = (int)NullableVersion;    // works now
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do an explicit cast, but why isn't the implicit conversion working ?

Comment: Most likely because you created a nullable version

Comment: Your code above is fine in .NET 4.5+, what version of .NET are you running?